# NextJs app loading slow on safari but fine on chrome, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, safari, image-optimization

I'm developing a web app with nextjs. I've found linking to pages (specifically home page, which loads multiple svgs and images) lags and doesn't even show loader while using safari, but I'm happy with the performance on chrome. I've seen people mention sharp, which I have installed. Others have mentioned slow development time but faster in production, not the case for me because i've tested in both environments. Any insight would be appreciated, as I said the performance lag seems specific to safari as I only find experience it on safari both mobile and desktop.

The production site here: [cloud9.atoffettidev.com](https://cloud9.atoffettidev.com)

The git repository here:
[git repo](https://github.com/anthonyss09/Portfolio.git)

Comment: Your github repo link leads to your deploy website again

Comment: I did some shallow review of your code, and I could not identify something that might cause bad performance. I am unable to answer your questions but I might be able to give you some tips. Just to know even tho Safari and Chrome are webkit browsers, Safari has a lot of catching up to do. My best guess is some of your animation code is causing Safari some problems. The best way to know for sure is install react dev tools on Safari if you have a iOS system and profile the app. It will tell you exactly where performance bottleneck is

Comment: Thank you for the time. I removed all event listeners and lag was the same, but when I removed all components (which hold the svgs and images) performance seemed better, so I’m lead to believe it’s the images or svgs. A little bummer because most people view these apps on iPhone/safari browser. But I will investigate further with dev tools.

Comment: I've posted an answer on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I narrowed the performance hits on safari browser down to the importing of numerous svgs on my home page. I was importing the svgs as react components laced with svg syntax, so I switched them to .svg files. Then I ran those .svg files through a optimizer/minifier and I got pretty good results using them in the nextjs Image element. Now there's not much difference if any between the app's performance on chrome and safari.